# HTML input type="file" not working in Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, file-upload, intel-xdk

I am building a Cordova android app using Intel XDK. (Cordova means HTML5, CSS and Javascript) 
I have this line of code inside a form in my code:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file">
```

The form works good, it's comunicating with the server, but when I try to upload a file it says:"this action cannot ne performed by any app." I only want to upload photos, I have Google Foto and the built-in Gallery apps installed, is there anything I can do to the code to perform the action of selecting the photo using the Gallery or Google Photo? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution on my own. I added `accept="image/*"` and everithing is working now. 
Everithing is ok, the file selector is now the built-in Gallery

Comment: Hi^ @Alex! Please edit the response and write down a complete example of using the attribute in the context of the input tag. E.g.:
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="upload_file">`